# ginstall: cannot stat 'Modules/_blake2.cpython-312-darwin.so':

Tags: python, macos

I was trying to install python 3.12.1 with asdf on macOS 14.2.1 (Sonoma)

```
python-build 3.12.1 /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/python/3.12.1
python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.12.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.1/Python-3.12.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.1...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.2.1 using python-build 2.3.35-11-g9908daf8)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/qx/vjzng4rs2pd9w20rh3x_fr3w0000gn/T/python-build.20240129095442.33260
Results logged to /var/folders/qx/vjzng4rs2pd9w20rh3x_fr3w0000gn/T/python-build.20240129095442.33260.log

Last 10 log lines:
      __locale_setlocale in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
      __locale_localeconv in _localemodule.o
  _libintl_textdomain, referenced from:
      __locale_textdomain in _localemodule.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_freeze_module] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Then I tried to `brew remove --ignore-dependencies gettext` as per the python bug https://bugs.python.org/issue46975

Then I got:

```
ginstall: cannot stat 'Modules/_blake2.cpython-312-darwin.so': No such file or directory
make: *** [sharedinstall] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2805

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
asdf install python 3.12.1
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Uninstalling OpenSSL 1.1 fixes the issue